# Long table running off page (vertically)

Tags: tables, tabularx, amsart

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\title{Title 1}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Col 1}                      & \textbf{Col 2}    & \textbf{Col 3} & \textbf{Col 4} \\ \hline
                htrhoi thitrih trhoirtohij  & gshgks grgk grkes  & tjftjtj                      &  jrngekgb rgrk rnejge rjgnreg lregnre gjegrenogeg ergnr egre gnerg lreg njergnerjg renlgrle gn relgjreng lrejgregn erlkgnre regrljgreglklg regre g reg ekrglkerk gergnrelg renger gnregrelkkfg g rgrkeek r igrgr gks msgr gkrgrlkegenr krngreklrgke klrg \\ \hline
        rgue gouergou reog rougroer     & riuege ug grue eugor grgmi reegurg rejgn rejgnerjg er  & trjhtrhbht   & rgj regrej gjrengrege gergklreg relkgerkg regkr rkgregergje j egrj greijg ergioerjre reig jergj ergj ergjrei jg ier jreijg jreig jergiejkkef iwefijew jigjw gwei iwr gjrgi jregjre erg jreg jregj erjgerigjrej erijg jegi rejgi ripgjerij  \\ \hline
                rgru rugruiuigrei   & greher                      & htklhtk tlhjt hltr htrh terhtruhlh rtnh trlh trnlhrtkj  & rjen jgnre jerg ljrgner reng rgre lgregjreg lkgergj erlgker gkljer rgjjkgtgr goriwgrg rig erger erg \\ \hline
                rgjrgjn rjgnrenjgjk                     & rthtrhthh                   & rjkg rjgerjg                & rgreg nrejge rngngrejk nregjnregre ngrejglr ergjljrgwlghgkhfe efh fkew fewfk hefkje hewjf hewfkjw fhewkj fueuf qefiqiuqfqefhqwuuqwfhqqufu fhqwq hwfueq fhequofhqeuq fhquifqwu fqwqfhwqufqwfuqw fhqufqhuq hquf q fq hfuqfheqfu eqfu eqhfu eqhfequf hqe \\ \hline
                gjnr gjek                                               & rejug ehrgerg enrgre gegirj regore ogrrg reljgg ergreg nhe ht & jg gk hgr k & gre gre jgrrgrjegkffr grew uwefe whifweh bwekjgr \\ \hline
                htrhoi thitrih trhoirtohij  & gshgks grgk grkes  & tjftjtj                      &  jrngekgb rgrk rnejge rjgnreg lregnre gjegrenogeg ergnr egre gnerg lreg njergnerjg renlgrle gn relgjreng lrejgregn erlkgnre regrljgreglklg regre g reg ekrglkerk gergnrelg renger gnregrelkkfg g rgrkeek r igrgr gks msgr gkrgrlkegenr krngreklrgke klrg \\ \hline
        rgue gouergou reog rougroer     & riuege ug grue eugor grgmi reegurg rejgn rejgnerjg er  & trjhtrhbht   & rgj regrej gjrengrege gergklreg relkgerkg regkr rkgregergje j egrj greijg ergioerjre reig jergj ergj ergjrei jg ier jreijg jreig jergiejkkef iwefijew jigjw gwei iwr gjrgi jregjre erg jreg jregj erjgerigjrej erijg jegi rejgi ripgjerij  \\ \hline
                rgru rugruiuigrei   & greher                      & htklhtk tlhjt hltr htrh terhtruhlh rtnh trlh trnlhrtkj  & rjen jgnre jerg ljrgner reng rgre lgregjreg lkgergj erlgker gkljer rgjjkgtgr goriwgrg rig erger erg \\ \hline
                rgjrgjn rjgnrenjgjk                     & rthtrhthh                   & rjkg rjgerjg                & rgreg nrejge rngngrejk nregjnregre ngrejglr ergjljrgwlghgkhfe efh fkew fewfk hefkje hewjf hewfkjw fhewkj fueuf qefiqiuqfqefhqwuuqwfhqqufu fhqwq hwfueq fhequofhqeuq fhquifqwu fqwqfhwqufqwfuqw fhqufqhuq hquf q fq hfuqfheqfu eqfu eqhfu eqhfequf hqe \\ \hline
                gjnr gjek                                               & rejug ehrgerg enrgre gegirj regore ogrrg reljgg ergreg nhe ht & jg gk hgr k & gre gre jgrrgrjegkffr grew uwefe whifweh bwekjgr \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the table stop at the bottom margin and continue to run over to the next page without it disappearing off into nowhere?

Comment: Package `longtable`, for example ... ;-)

Comment: Instead of using a `tabularx` environment inside a `table` environment, you should use the `longtable` and `ltxtable` packages, as is exlained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214551/5001.